# implement android:stretchColumns="*" programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I am working on an application that implements the aforementioned property in the TableLayout.

I was wondering could anyone please help me and show me how to do this programmatically and not in the layout file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout for [`setColumnStretchable (int columnIndex, boolean isStretchable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setColumnStretchable%28int,%20boolean%29) in the Android Docs.

> Makes the given column stretchable or not. When stretchable, a column
>   takes up as much as available space as possible in its row. Calling
>   this method requests a layout operation.

[`setStretchAllColumns (boolean stretchAllColumns)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#setStretchAllColumns%28boolean%29) -

> Convenience method to mark all columns as stretchable.

Comment: in the xml layout, I set it android:stretchColumns="*" and then I add row to the table programatically but the column don't stretch at all. I also tried setStretchAllColumns(true) but doesn't work at all